# Can any of sum of squares be realized as a sum of this specific form?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, and suppose that $x^2+y^2 \ge 4$.
Do there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$
(a+d)^2+(b-c)^2=x^2+y^2
$
and $ad-bc=1$?

---

This question is motivated by an attempt to characterise the norms of matrices in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$: If $A =\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then
$$
(a+d)^2+(b-c)^2=\|A\|^2+2,
$$
so I wonder whether $\|A\|^2+2$ can be any sum of squares.

Comment: Do you refer to the general case, i.e. $x,y$ are arbitrary integers with $x^2+y^2\geqslant 4$, or are you asking if there are any $x,y$ satisfying the properties you mention?

Comment: This is clearly about the general case. If the first sentence doesn't make it clear, the last one certainly does ("any sum of squares")

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Indeed, this is about the general case, i.e. I am asking if for *any* $x,y$, $x^2+y^2$ can be expressed as a certain sum of squares with $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=1$ and $y=3$ so that $x^2+y^2=10$. Then if $\tbinom{a\ b}{c\ d}\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb{Z})$ is such that
$$(a+d)^2+(b-c)^2=x^2+y^2=10,\tag{1}$$
then $\{a+d,b-c\}=\{\pm 1,\pm 3\}$ for some for some choices of the signs. Then of course the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}-a&\hphantom{-}b\\\hphantom{-}c&-d\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}\hphantom{-}a&-b\\-c&\hphantom{-}d\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}\hphantom{-}b&\hphantom{-}a\\-d&-c\end{pmatrix}
\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb{Z}),$$
also satisfy $(1)$, so without loss of generality $a+d=1$ and $b-c=3$. Then
$$1=ad-bc=a(1-a)-b(b-3),$$
which shows that $b$ is an integral root of a quadratic with discriminant
$$\Delta=-4a^2+4a+5.$$
But this is never a perfect square; a contadiction! Hence no such matrix exists.

Comment: Nice example, but I find it easier to argue by parity. If $x$ and $y$ are both odd, and $x^2 + y^2 = (a+d)^2 + (b-c)^2$, then $a+d$ as well as $b-c$ must be odd, hence one of $a$ and $d$, and one of $b$ and $c$ must be even, whence $ad - bc$ is even.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that's a nice argument! (I guess you are looking at $\mod 4$). I asked a follow-up question - I wonder whether this is the only obstruction. It's here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898637/expression-of-sum-of-squares-as-a-sum-of-a-specific-form

Comment: @Servaes Thank for this interesting answer. Can you please tell how do you see that $-4a^2+4a+5.$ is never a perfect square?

Comment: For $a=0,1$ it equals $5$, for all other values of $a$ it is negative.